# Amazon boto3 download file from S3 to tempfile

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Python has the ability to create a tempfile as a context manager. Rather than having to make a directory myself, along with the path, and then cleaning it up when done, it would be better to use this tempfile.

Is there any support in the boto3 client to download, from s3, to a tempfile?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try the [download_fileobj](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.download_fileobj) method which accepts a file-like object and requires binary mode, for example:

```
import boto3
import tempfile

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

with tempfile.TemporaryFile(mode='w+b') as f:
    s3.download_fileobj('mybucket', 'mykey', f)
```

Comment: When I tried above logic, it downloads files as some temp name, but I want to download the original filename from s3 key. Reason is I want to download file and attach to send it via email or post to HTTP

Comment: @Kar The code shown deliberately creates a temporary file because that was what the original question asked for. If you want to control the name of the file then use regular Python file i/o for a named file.

Comment: @Kar Try using NamedTemporaryFile, it would you give you greater flexibility https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile