# Download s3 file to temporary file

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, temporary-files

I am writing a script that will download a large number of files from s3. I know I can write all the files to a directory and then use the files from that point. I really want the text contained within these s3 files but considering that there is a lot I would like to avoid downloading them all. In the past, I have downloaded them to a junk directory and then deleted the directory but I want a more elegant solution. Below is my code for downloading info from s3

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)
# select bucket
my_bucket = s3.Bucket('<bucket_name>')
for item in my_bucket.objects.all():
    my_bucket.download_file(item.key, f'../<junk_directory>/{filename}')
```

I would like to ideally use the `tempfile` package as it seems to fit my needs nicely. Is there a way to pass a tempfile to the `filename` parameter in `download_file`?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983886/python-writing-and-reading-from-a-temporary-file) stack question talks about manipulating temporary files and I cannot think how to modify the solution to work with s3. How would I temporarily download s3 content for storage and performance gains?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44043036/how-to-read-image-file-from-s3-bucket-directly-into-memory. It is for an image but can be used for any type of content

Comment: Ooh. This looks really useful. I will try this and update the question if that was a correct answer!

Comment: Does it make sense to store a pdf as StringIO or BytesIO?

Comment: well technically everything is bytes and if it suits your use case then should be good but i am kind of curious what do you want to do the pdf next

Comment: download the pdf, convert it to a txt file and then process the txt file

Comment: Then i guess it depends on your choice of library too, because most would take a file object see the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44045097/5660284)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222756/discussion-between-josh-zwiebel-and-venky).

Comment: See also [Amazon boto3 download file from S3 to tempfile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58441526/1048572)